# How to indent PHP code in PHP-mode?

Tags: java, php-mode

I come from Java/Netbeans, and I can indent my Java code using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, 
I have searched through this site and other articles, but I didn't find a good way to indent PHP.

What I found:

1. > using pear PHP_beautifier

but I have to output the result to a different file or simply copy on terminal result.

2. > using PHP beautifier on the web

I have tried using M-x indent-region in PHP-mode but nothing changes. I tried in jdee for Java code M-x indent-region also doesn't work.

I found other solutions but for JSON, com.lang, Asytle (C/C++/C#)

this is my .emacs

https://gist.github.com/azzamsa/1f76b8ca00fd2737ae08a5c3f6dc6b3f

I am using :

php-mode-1.18.2(ejmr/php-mode), GNU Emacs 24.4.1

and installed php-mode from elpa repo.

After following phils suggestion to use <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it **works**. But when I try to break the code format, and try to see the result using <kbd>C-x</kbd>+ <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it doesn't indent the code properly as what online formater does. e.g.:

```
    public function

        __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        //$this->numLeg = $numLeg;
    }

    public

        function

            bark() {
            return "Woof!";
        }
    public

        function

            greet() {
            return "hello i am " . "$this->name";
        }


}
```

There is no result even when I use `indent-region`. I also tried to use fill-region, and other choice of fill, but no luck. But the online formatter can handle this nicely, the result from [online formatter](http://beta.phpformatter.com/) and the expected one is:

```
class Dog {
    public $numLegs = 4;
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        //$this->numLeg = $numLeg;
    }

    public function bark() {
        return "Woof!";
    }
    public function greet() {
        return "hello i am " . "$this->name";
    }


}
$dog1 = new Dog("Barker");
$dog2 = new DOg("Amigo");
```

Comment: `indent-region` (usually invoked via `TAB`) is the correct answer, so you should show an example of what isn't working for you (with the original formatting, and the formatting you are *expecting* to see after reindenting).

Comment: Also say which version of Emacs you are using, and which php-mode (where you got it from, as well as version) you are using.

Comment: (After reading the updated question): `indent-region` deals only with *indentation*, not joining statements which are (bizarrely) split over multiple lines into single lines. It doesn't reformat your code; it just sets the indent of each line. In other words, what you're asking for *isn't* "how to indent PHP code". I don't think `php-mode` can help you, so you might as well continue to use the other tools you've found.

Comment: thankfully now i can continue to learn php in emacs after your answer.  thanks lot for your great answer and suggestion, really thanks.
may i know what tool you use for reformating PHP or Java code in emacs ?.

Comment: I've rarely had a need for anything like that. I format my own code the way it ought to be formatted (with Emacs indenting), and I'm unlikely to want to introduce version-control noise by reformatting code I'm *not* working on, so I generally don't do that (and coding standards make that an unusual need in any case). The small amount of reformatting I do is manual. I'll take a look at `php-beautifier.el` though.

Comment: oh, thank you very much, for your explanation, thanks. Yes, I have tried it, and it works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is **solved**.

Thanks to Phil Newton (sodaware) for creating [this](https://github.com/Sodaware/php-beautifier.el) extension to integrate with PHP_beautifier.

This application was released 5 hours ago (on March 28, 2017).

I have tried some of my PHP Code, and it works well.

This is some gif from when I gave it a try.

[image: php_beautifier_el_1]